# What is the number after the index in terminal?

Tags: command-line

After typing for example, `firefox &` or `xpad &` in terminal, the echoed output looks like

`[number of background programs running] <an unknown number>`

What does that unknown number signify?

Except that they are always increasing, they do not seem to follow any particular order, are they some kind of time indicators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number is the PID of the application.

PID is a process identifier. Each application run by a user is assigned a number. To learn more about it please refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier)